# Backbase redirection issue

Tags: redirect, backbase, backbase-portal

I'm running a portal based on Backbase and I have recently added a new LINK file (let's call it `myLastLinkPath`) in the following path:

- *src/main/import-scripts/portal/myPortal/links*

The problem now is that when I access (through the browser) to my site, it redirects automatically to the last added link.

I mean, if I go to **www.mysyte.com**, it is redirectected to **www.mysite.com/myLastLinkPath**

Answer (score 2):

It is the *Default Landing Page* of your portal.

You can check this in the portal configuration page, in the *special pages* tab